# How to include an external library in C++ project with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to make a C++ project work, using the intel mkl library.
This project consists of a general library and some application examples. This is how the directories tree looks like

```
Project
|- General library
|--- CMakeLists.txt
|--- .h, .cpp
|- MKL
|- Examples folder
|--- CMakeLists.txt
|----- Example 1 folder
|------- CMakeLists.txt
```

I can make it work in my computer by including the mkl necessary files in the example CMakeLists.txt but when I try to run the generated executable in another machine it gives me this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmkl_rt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My goal is to be able to generate an executable file for the examples that can be used by itself in other computers.
It is my first time using cmake and I am a little lost.
After reading the cmake tutorials I have tried adding `include_directories`, `target_link_libraries` and such, but with no success.

Is it possible to make what I intend? How should I proceed?

Comment: "My goal is to be able to generate an executable file for the examples that can be used by itself in other computers." - You cannot use an executable without **shared** libraries linked into it.

Comment: You should link against MKL statically.

Comment: As mentioned above, you should either link against *static* MKL libraries, or install the shared libraries on the target machine. To link statically use a CMake command like `find_library(LIBMKL_RT libmkl_rt.a)`. Also please post the relevant CMake code next time.